# Container on worker node is not accessible using Swarm Mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have a Swarm cluster with a Manager and a Worker node.
All the containers running on the manager are accessible through Traefik and working fine.
I just deployed a new Worker node and joined my swarm on the node.
Now I start scaling some services and realized they were timing out on the worker node.

So I setup a simple example using the `whoami` container, and cannot figure out why I cannot access it. Here are my configs (all deployed on the MANAGER node):

```
version: '3.6'

networks:
  traefik-net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    external: true
services:
  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami    
    networks:
      - traefik-net 
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=8000"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.myhost.com"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role != manager]
```

My traefik:

```
version: '3.6'

networks:
  traefik-net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    external: true
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --docker --docker.swarmmode --docker.domain=myhost.com --docker.watch --api  
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
#      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen 
      - /home/ubuntu/docker-configs/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /home/ubuntu/docker-configs/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.port: 8080
        traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:traefik.myhost.com"
        traefik.docker.network: traefik-net
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

My worker `docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b825f95b0366        jwilder/whoami:latest   "/app/http"         4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          8000/tcp            whoami_whoami.2.tqbh4csbqxvsu6z5i7vizc312
50cc04b7f0f4        jwilder/whoami:latest   "/app/http"         4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          8000/tcp            whoami_whoami.1.rapnozs650mxtyu970isda3y4
```

I tried opening firewall ports, disabling it completely, nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `--advertise-addr y.y.y.y` to make it work